# Как найти координаты у изображения и по ним сделать триггер

Tags: python, opencv

Картинка :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно как то найти координаты x (левая красная полоска) и координаты y (правая красная полоска)
и сделать между ними триггер что бы изображения поплавка не заходила за них, а если заходила то возвращалось обратно
Чтобы найти координаты точек в зоне, я использую инструментами для анализа изображений, такой как OpenCV

Код :

```
template = cv2.imread("2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

color_yellow = (0, 255, 255)

mon = {'top': 80, 'left': 350, 'width': 100, 'height': 100}


# Задайте начальные координаты поплавка
initial_x = None

def process_image(original_image):
    processed_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    processed_image = cv2.Canny(processed_image, threshold1=200, threshold2=300)
    return processed_image
```

Comment: вам надо использовать `Template Matching`: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html, делать это лучше в CV_32F предварительно вычтя из картинок среднее (mean)

Comment: Да здесь много чего можно придумать - анализ гистограммы по цветовым каналам или в HSV в скользящим окне, например. Или тот же поиск шаблона, но с использованием поиска особых точек. Или просто порог по цвету. Но тот "великий и могучий русский языка", что можно наблюдать в этом сообщении отбивает даже желание его править.